# Permanence time in a markov chain

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process, statistical-mechanics, renewal-processes

For a continuous-time Markov process with, say, two states $1,2$ and transition rates $r_{ik}$, over a time interval of duration $T$, what is the probability $P(t)$ of spending, in total, a duration $t$ in state $1$?

Comment: Do you want a total duration of $t$ perhaps through several visits?

Answer (score 0):

If we begin in state $1$ at time $0$, then the probability of staying in state $1$ at least until time $t$ is $r_{11}^t$.  So, the probability of staying in state $1$ until time $t$ and then transitioning is $r_{11}^tr_{12}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X(t)$ be the state the system is in at time $t$. The generator matrix is given by
$$
G = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 -\lambda  & \lambda  \\
 \mu  & -\mu  \\
\end{array}
\right).
$$
From Kolmogorov's backward equation $P'(t) = GP(t)$, we find that $P(t) = e^{Gt}$, where $P_{ij}(t) = \mathbb P(X(t)=j\mid X(0)=i)$. Here
$$
e^{Gt} = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{\lambda e^{-(\lambda +\mu )t}  +\mu }{\lambda +\mu } & \frac{\lambda -\lambda e^{-(\lambda +\mu )t}  }{\lambda +\mu } \\
 \frac{\mu(1-e^{-(\lambda +\mu )t})  }{\lambda +\mu } & \frac{\lambda +\mu e^{-(\lambda +\mu )t}  }{\lambda +\mu } \\
\end{array}
\right),
$$
so the probability of spending a duration of $t$ in state $1$ over an interval $T$ (assuming $X(0)=1$ is given by
\begin{align}
\frac{\int_0^t P_{11}(s)\ \mathsf ds}{\int_0^T P_{11}(s)\ \mathsf ds} &= \frac{\int_0^t \frac{\lambda e^{-(\lambda +\mu )s}  +\mu }{\lambda +\mu }\ \mathsf ds}{\int_0^T \frac{\lambda e^{-(\lambda +\mu )s}  +\mu }{\lambda +\mu }\ \mathsf ds}\\ &= \frac{\frac{\lambda +\lambda  \left(-e^{-t (\lambda +\mu )}\right)+\mu  t (\lambda +\mu )}{(\lambda +\mu )^2}}{\frac{\lambda +\lambda  \left(-e^{-T (\lambda +\mu )}\right)+\mu  T (\lambda +\mu )}{(\lambda +\mu )^2}}\\
&= \frac{\lambda\left(1-e^{-(\lambda +\mu )t}\right)+\mu   (\lambda +\mu )t}{\lambda\left(1-e^{-(\lambda +\mu )T}\right)+\mu   (\lambda +\mu )T}.
\end{align}